# Django - Class Function not returning page

Tags: python, django, function, class

I am trying to create code for my Django site which will take the user's input, perform a calculation, and then send the data back to the user in the form of a new page, however everytime I run the code, it does not create the new page nor does it post the results.

Below is the function itself.

```
def SparkCalc(request):
    new_item = sparkCalculator()
    new_item.tix = request.POST['tix']
    new_item.tenrolls = request.POST['tenrolls']
    new_item.crystals = request.POST['crystals']
    new_item.save()
    total = new_item.getTotal()
    return render(request, 'SparkResults.html', {"title": "Spark Results"}, {"total": total})
```

and below is the Django page I am calling it from:

```
<form action="/SparkCalc/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <label for ="tix">Please enter your single roll tickets</label>
    <input type="text" id="tix" name="tix"/>
    <label for ="tenrolls">Please enter your ten-roll tickets</label>
    <input type="text" id="tenrolls" name="tenrolls"/>
    <label for ="tix">Please enter your total crystal amount</label>
    <input type="text" id="crystals"name="crystals"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Get Results"/>    
</form>
```

And finally below is the class I created:

```
class sparkCalculator(models.Model): 
    tix = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    tenrolls = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    crystals = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def getTotal(self): 
        return (int(self.tix)*300) + (int(self.tenrolls)* 3000) + int(self.crystals)
```

The way I envision the code to work is that once the user enters their information into the form, Django then runs the SparcCalc function, collecting the information entered, performing the math and collecting a total, and then sending the total to the new page. Instead, it seems to be just refreshing the page.

Also is it possible to run this style of code without creating an entire class for it? This is not information I would want to store. Ideally I would just want it executed at runtime and to be done with it, but previous attempts at doing this have failed and I simply gave up and tried creating a class.

As far as I can tell it is correctly entered into my urlpatterns.

```
from catalog.views import (
    SparkCalc,
    sparkCalcPage,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('SparkCalc/', sparkCalcPage),
    path('SparkResults/', SparkCalc),
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `render` function is as follows:

```
def render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, ...):
   ...
```

In your case,  you have passed `{'total':total}` to the `content_type` keyword argument instead of `context`.

```
# also make sure 'SparkResults.html' can be found by the template loader 
render(request, 'SparkResults.html', {"title": "Spark Results", "total": total})
```

Also, you need to submit your data to the corrent view.

```
<form action="/SparkResults/" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
    ...   
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
I've made the following changes to the code but so far the situation hasn't changed. I'm actually getting the same exact error. 
```
 return render(request, 'SparkResults.html', {"title": "Spark Results", 'total': total})
```
I'm also including the page it should be leading to incase maybe that's the problem. I've purposely kept it very plain for the purpose of testing. 

```
{% extends "base.html %}
{% block content %}
<p>{{ total }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: That last part about sending the data to the correct view was it!
THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a model for the task,
perform the operation in the views.py itself.

```
def SparkCalc(request):
    tix = request.POST['tix']
    tenrolls = request.POST['tenrolls']
    crystals = request.POST['crystals']
    total = (int(tix)*300) + (int(tenrolls)* 3000) + int(crystals)
    return render(request, 'SparkResults.html', {"title": "Spark Results"}, {"total": total})
```